# Deriving the universal cubic Bezier equations from the "start", "control" and "end" points

Tags: polynomials, parametric

If the four points of a cubic Bézier curve are known, how do you derive algebraically the universal equations of that curve (which is, one equation for $x$ and the other for $y$)? Let's say I have:

- $A: (x_0,y_0)$, start point,
- $B: (x_1,y_1)$, control point,
- $C: (x_2,y_2)$, control point,
- $D: (x_3, y_3)$, end point.

I have attempted deriving the formula using vectors, however it did not quite work out. I have, however, been able to successfully derive the universal equations for a quadratic Bézier curve.

Any help or hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You may want to use Latex for the formulas. Check the "edit" for some little hint. Welcome to MSE!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve